# Options for deploying basic ML scripts with serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, scikit-learn, serverless, amazon-sagemaker

An API I am building on AWS Lambda has some basic scikit-learn/numpy operations, such as vector arithmetic and clustering. However, the dependencies are very large (scipy = 100M+) and cause issues with deployment limits for a lot of the serverless solutions out there (e.g. lambda = 250MB limit). These dependencies also exceed layer limits.

I'm guessing this is a basic problem for ML engineers, so I'm wondering what the defacto practice for a microservice based architectures is. Is it typical for organizations to host all custom ML logic to a service like AWS Sagemaker, even if it's something as simple as SKLearn? Note: I'm not looking to migrate to docker ([asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585329/is-there-a-way-to-get-around-the-250-mb-limit-for-an-aws-lambda-function)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. SageMaker offers 1P(first party) containers in your case for SKLearn([here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container)) that you could leverage to host. Additonally, SageMaker offers Serverless Inference where you don't need to configure any instances behind the endpoint explicitly, you can provide the max_concurrency and memory that your model requires. Some examples on Serverless Inference can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/serverless-inference).